# how to get sidebar scrolling like wired website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend, sidebar, sticky

i have tried to replicate the **sibebar scrolling** used on **wired.com** but no luck yet :/

**link** - https://www.wired.com/story/the-bike-share-war-is-shaking-up-seattle-like-nowhere-else/

few things i have noticed-

1. the sidebar changes height dynamically depending on the content(can be a big picture or an ad) which is wider than the content in the middle portion
2. then it gets pushed up by that content.
3. After all have moved up, the sidebar appears again and sticks until it comes in contact with any such content.

   i checked the source and it seems the sidebar is finding the height of the wider content and matching to it , and then the next , and in the last its 100%

[image]

PS - i am new to web development and any help would be immensely  appreciated :) , thanks:

Comment: You mentioned that you tried to replicate it. Can you share your attempt?

Comment: i tried it in sections, first i tried to show the sidebar when it reaches the top and kept it sticky using css, then i tried matching the height of the sidebar to the first wide content in the article , it worked, it went up with the content, but the problem is i am not able to bring it back for the second wide content in the article, sorry i used the wrong word, it should be trying, not tried :) , plus i dont even know if my i am thinking the right way

Comment: To be able to help improve your code, we need to see your code.

Answer (score 0):

this is what i have tried

```
        $(function(){
    var d = $('#sidebar');
    var dPosTop = d.offset().top;
    var win = $(window);
    win.scroll(function(e){
        var scrollTop = win.scrollTop();
        if(scrollTop >= dPosTop){
          d.fadeIn(500);
        }
      else{
        d.fadeOut(200);
      }
    });

});


$(document).ready(function(){
$("#sidebar").height( $("#content").height() );
});
```

Comment: i found the same on the national geographic website https://www.nationalgeographic.com/magazine/2018/07/building-a-better-athlete/ . I think wired.com does an amazing job with that, especially with the ads which appear full width, beautiful full scale ads without intruding much with the content.